# JavaScript Function should return array

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, return

I am trying to retrieve a particular type of files from a folder in JavaScript. I am using Regex and module 'fs' for it.
The function I am trying to build doesn't return anything.I can see the array once I print it, but I am not able to return it. What I want is that the function should return an array of names of those particular files.
Here is the code

```
var fs = require('fs');
var dir = '/../../';
var ext = 'yml';
function test1 () {
  var c = new Array();
  fs.readdir(dir, function (err, list) {
    var re = new RegExp("^.*\." + ext + "$");
    list.forEach(function(item) {
    if(re.test(item)) {
      c.push(item);
    }

    // return item;
  });

  console.log(c)

  });
  // return c //
}
```

Comment: If you want to return an array, you are probably looking for the synchronus version of readdir https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options

Comment: Why do you want to return item from within readdir? That doesn't get caught anywhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are two layers deep in not being able to return a value directly from your function - `readdir` is asynchronous and `forEach` doesn't return values from the supplied callback. Try [readdirSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options) instead and use `filter` to remove non-matching files.

```
function test1() {
   var files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
   return files.filter(function(item) {
      return re.test(item);
   });
}
```

Or more succintly:

```
function test1() {
   return fs.readdirSync(dir).filter(re.test);
}
```

Comment: @M.D Could you please accept this answer as correct if it fixed your issue

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing synchronous and asynchronous functions. You can't write a function that returns a result in you make an asynchronous call to fs.readdir. You either need to make a call to the synchronous version fs.readdirSync or, instead of retuning a result, reconstruct your function so it takes a reference to a callback function and then calls that function and passes the result as a parameter. Method 2 is the normal Node.js way of doing things.

The way you have written it, your function returns before readdir has a chance to do its thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return because you're inside of a `forEach` function. Here's the solution using a for loop, which you can in fact return from

```
var fs = require('fs');
var dir = '/../../';
var ext = 'yml';
function test1() {
  var c = new Array();
  var tmp = null;
  fs.readdirSync( dir, function(err, list) {
    var re = new RegExp("^.*\." + ext + "$");
    for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      var item = list[i];
      // in your example, if doesn't have any {}. This is bad.
      if(re.test(item) ) {
          c.push(item);
          // not sure why you said you wanted to return item here
          // but you're inside of another function so you can't.
          // Only way to do so is to set it equal to a variable
          // this function has closed around.
          // tmp = item;
      }
      });

    console.log(c)
  });
  return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't return the file using fs.readdir(), because it just executes a callback asynchronously when the file read is done. Then the file object itself is passed to the callback as a parameter.

If you want to return the result of readdir, you have two options:

1) Use the [synchronous version of readdir](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options): this will return the file system as you wish, however, **it blocks the node single thread until its done**, and that can cause absolutely undesired behaviours on your program, and f.i. can be a serious issue in a web application (all request from every client will be blocked until readdirsync is done).

2) Use a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). A Promise doesn't actually return values like synchronous code, but lets you to control the flow of your asynchronous code like it was synchronous, [letting you to throw exceptions and chain return values in your code](https://gist.github.com/domenic/3889970).

F.i., an example of using Promises using the Bluebird implementation ([which requires to install the bluebird package](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html)):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var dir = '/../../';
var ext = 'yml';
var readdirAsync = Promise.promisify(fs.readdir);
//var c = new Array(); You dont need c as a global now, since you can return the result of the function from inside the iterateOverDir function.

/*Now this function returns a Promise that will pass the readdir value when the promise is fullfilled*/
var test1 = function() {
   /*yeah a single line function is pretty redundant but is to keep consistence with the OP code*/
   return fs.readdirAsync(dir);
}
/*
and this function just iterates over list performing some actions and 
returning a 'result' array. When this whole function is passed as a parameter in a .then(), it takes whatever the function inside the previous then/promise returns, and pass its return value to the next. This is true whenever the previous promise/then is synchronous or asynchronous code.
*/
var iterateOverDir = function(list){
   var re = new RegExp("^.*\." + ext + "$");
   list.forEach(function(item) {
     var result = new Array();
     if(re.test(item)) {
     result.push(item);
   }
   return result;
}
test1.then(iterateOverDir).catch(console.log)
then(console.log /* or whatever function that uses the previous function return value.*/);
```

Now,thanks of Promise, you can pipe to iterateOverDir() -which is plain synchronous code- every value from plain synchronous code or asynchronous. However, you must to keep your code inside the .then().then()... chains.